# How to check if the substring is present in the parent string in same order

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dynamic-programming

Input

```
Indian
3
nda
dan
ndani
```

Output

```
True
True
False
```

Explanation
1st line is the parent string
2nd line is the number of test case
The next n lines are the queries

First and Second query substring are in same order as in parent string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating a regular expression from the substring you are trying to match. For example, for the first test case if you want to know if 'nda' can be found in 'Indian', then form the regular expression `n.*d.*a` and do a search for that expression in 'Indian':

```py
import re

string = 'Indian'
substrings = [
    'nda',
    'dan',
    'ndan1'
]

for substring in substrings:
    rex = '.*'.join(re.escape(ch) for ch in substring) # 'n.*d.*a'
    print('True' if re.search(rex, string) else 'False')
```

Prints:

```
True
True
False
```

Answer (score 1):

for each query, initialize a pointer at the beginning of the query string, increment it only when you match an alphabet from the parent string while looping through the parent string

```
start = 0
for x in parent:
    if x == query[start]:
        start += 1
        if start == len(query):
            print(True)
            break
else:
    print(False)
```

You can do this for each query.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check each char against the main string index from i to end.
You can try this:

```
main_str = 'Indian'
words = ['nda','dan','ndani']

for word in words:
    checker = []

    for i in range(len(main_str)):
        if i == len(word):
            break

        if word[i] in main_str[i::]:
            checker.append('True')
        else:
            checker.append('False')

    if 'False' in checker:
        print('False')
    else:
        print('True')
```

It's not very efficient and intuitive but it gets the jobe done (I think). You can just modify the code to fit your input

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple program. But it will work -

```
string = 'Indian'
words = ['3','nda','dan','ndani']

for sub in words:
    if sub in the string:
       return True
    else:
       return False
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach - use **iter**.

```
def isSubsequence(sub: str, orig: str) -> bool:

    it = iter(orig)            # 

    return all(ch in orig for ch in sub)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sub =  'rice'
    orig =  'practice'

    assert isSubsequence(sub, orig)   == True
    assert isSubsequence('pace', orig)  == True
    assert isSubsequence('acts', orig)  == False
```